# Php require template for multiple pages

Tags: php, templates, include, require

Hi currently I have a page that looks like:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php include blahblah;?>
<div>
    <?php include blahblah;?>
</div>
<p>
    Wordswordswords
</p>
<?php include blahblah;?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have this as a norm across my site and it would be pretty difficult to change the format of the site later on. I was wondering if it would be acceptable to set php variables at the beginning of the document and then proceeding to require the template, for example:

```
<?php
    $words = 'words words words';
    $blahdi = 'more words words';
    require template;
?>
```

I understand that this will work but would it be good "coding etiquette" or have any drawbacks?

Comment: I can only tell you this, the second approach is better in general.

Comment: try to learn   twig or smarty  templete engine.